# Custom toolbar on android navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer, toolbar

Im new to android development and am really struggling to implement a more custom toolbar (or action bar) when using the navigation drawer created in android studio. When I created the navigation drawer activity from the template, the file that seems to be defining the tool bar is app_bar_main.xml 
here is app_bar_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:title="Press"
        android:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see, I have tried to change the title (to press) and text color of the tool bar, however when running it, nothing changes and it still just says MainActivity which is what my Navigation drawer activity is called. How can I define this toolbar so I can customize it (center the title, make the background transparent, remove settings button, etc. I do need to keep the hamburger icon to open the drawer obviously)
Thanks for the future help everyone! Let me know if I need to provide any other pieces of my code

Comment: Post the whole layout code, styles, and post your onCreate method. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the values inside of xml for the toolbar has never worked for me either. You should do them pragmatically. If you are generating the code from Android Studio, you will see inside of onCreate that it is setting the toolbar to the ActionBar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

One possible option is to remove setSupportActionbar().

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Testing");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

The other is to call getSupprtActionBar()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Testing");
    }
}

/**
 * Here is where you would handle the actionbar items. 
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help! I used your first method that you showed and it worked perfectly. Now, I was wondering if you could help me center the title and make the menu transparent? I do not see any methods showing for changing the alignment of the title

Comment: @GarrettHuff Yes I can give you a hand with that, just reply to this and I will give you my email, so we can talk off the thread.

Comment: Sounds good, ready for the address unless there is a way for me to message you here directly, not sure if you were going to leave your email on this thread. If not, tell me what to do (im new to stack overflow). Thanks!